What do "steps" in "you must implement every step" mean in legal parlance?
While researching implications of a patent on a business idea, I read this explanation in one of the answers here on Ask Patents:

Remember, to infringe on a patent, you must implement every step of at least one claim. Thus, if a claim has steps A, B, and C and you only implement A and C, you should avoid infringement.

I have trouble translating this into practice, and I hoped someone here could explain what this means on a concrete case.
Let's take the patent here: Systems, Methods, and Media for Presenting Panel-Based Electronic Documents [US20100318895A1] -- the famous (at least in my circles) Comixology/Amazon patent for showing comics panel by panel on a computer, granted 2018 and in effect until 2031. This is the same patent that was the subject of the answer above. It doesn't explicitly label and "steps" with things like A), B) or C).
The patent is for this kind of moving between panels of a digital comics:



This patent has 27 claims. Most of these are "a method of claim X", which I hope means they only apply when taken in the context of their parent claim. So, for example:


The method of claim 10, wherein the definition of the first panel is in an XML format.


I hope I understand correctly that this doesn't prevent anyone from having software that has panels in it, and the panels are defined using an XML format. That would be silly. It only applies to claim 10, right? So, this is not a "step" nor a "claim"?
Claim 10 states:


A method for presenting panel-based electronic documents, comprising:

receiving an electronic document, a definition of a first panel on a page in the electronic document, and a definition of a second panel on the page in the electronic document;
controlling a display of the first panel based on the definition of the first panel; and
transitioning from the display of the first panel to a display of the second panel by re-scaling the display and panning from the first panel to the second panel.

Now, do I understand this correctly that the three last paragraphs above are the "steps"? So, for example, if someone were to present comics in a digital medium panel by panel, but instead of smoothly transitioning from one to the other (step 3), they would just show them one by one (as in a picture gallery), this patent would not apply?
Or is it that the sub-claims (like #13 above) are the steps, and so even just deviating from using an XML file would make one's application non-infringing?

Just to be clear, the cited document is only an application, not a patent. Claims in applications are nearly always edited in granted patents and may be overly broad. you'll find claim 13 significantly different in the patent. The resultant patent is here: https://patents.google.com/patent/US9886936B2/en

The dependent claims do include all the constraints of the referenced parent claim. Claim 13 could have been written by appending the new limitation to the text of claim 10. It would have the same effect. Dependent claims cost the applicant less than independent claims and provide clarity without comparing word by word. If you infringe 13 you have, by definition, also infringed 10.
Dependent claims like 13 are claims they are not sub-claims or steps.
You are correct that each of those three paragraphs is a step. The key word announcing a step is a gerund like moving, recognizing, lifting, stirring.
Leaving out a step or changing a step can avoid infringement but substituting or modifying a step can sometimes be viewed as “equivalent”. In that case you do not avoid infringement.
Also, if you perform any single claim you infringe the patent.
The steps or elements in a claim are not usually explicitly labeled like A, B and C.

Thank you for the clear explanation. I wish all legal explanations were like this!
Let me try to apply what I understood. First, someone pointed out that https://patents.google.com/patent/US9886936B2/en is the granted patent. In that patent, only (dependent) claim 9 talks about animation. So, a non-animated gallery of comics panels that shows them in sequence potentially infringes on the patent? (Because claim 9 is not a "step"?)

You might want to ask this as a new question. If you do, please make it more clear. It doesn’t matter (other than subtle corner cases) whether a claim that you infringe is depends or independent.
